# Can I have different Apple IDs on my iPhone 4S?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-id

iCloud has an Apple ID:

```
Settings > iCloud
```

Messages has an Apple ID:

```
Settings > Message > Receive At
```

Store has an Apple ID:

```
Setting > Store
```

Do these all have to be the same ID?  If not, which ones can be different?

Or to ask this question a different way...

My wife and I both have a 4S.  Can we share the same ID for iCloud (calendar sync) and Store (app sync) but not for Messages (distinct text identity)?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each place you mention is separate so you can use a unique Apple ID in each. Other than the App Store / Music Store where you can only enroll 10 devices in a 90 day period), you can use one account on many, many devices.

In addition, the iCloud account that is entered into iCloud does control Photo Stream, Documents and Backup for the entire device.

Your additional iCloud accounts can be entered into Mail, Contacts, Calendars to have additional:

- Mail
- Contacts
- Calendars
- Reminders
- Bookmarks
- Notes
- Find My iPhone

Answer (score 2):

You can both use separate IDs for iCloud—email, calendar and backups—and still [share a calendar](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2690). iCloud allows you to share calendars with other members on read only or read/write basis. [iMessages](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3529) can be tied to your iCloud Apple ID or phone number.

You should both use the same Apple ID for iTunes store purchases so you can share media and app purchases.

Comment: Do this; you won't regret it.  Each person with his/her own account is the way to go for iCloud.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful.  I'm going to have to try sharing calendars with different accounts.

Comment: So while the link to sharing calendars was very helpful, I couldn't do it.  My wife and I need to share calendars and contacts.  Yeah, sorry, I didn't mention contacts in my original post.  As far as I can tell, we can share calendars and reminders, but not contacts.  I'd love for someone to prove me wrong...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, you can have separate ID's for iCloud / Messaging and iTunes

Your iCloud and iTunes store Apple ID can be different and I am using that configuration.

Answer (score -1):

So we have ONE iPhone5 between 2 of us. My wife has her APP store id associated with the iPhone. It appears only one APP store id is allowed per iPhone device. It would be nice if I could logon to the APP store with my Apple ID on this iPhone, without her losing her application information.

Example: APP X has information sent only to me on my macbook. APP X has an APP Store application that we can load onto our one and only iphone5. But if we load APP X's APP store application onto our iphone5, the information sent to me will not be displayed nor coordinated with APP X's APP store application.

Apple should really allow 2 different APP store ID's to be used on one iPhone. The users could then logon to the other ID to load up other app's!